# Initialisation of first object is different from other objects, what is the best way to handle it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I am working with a chain like structure of an object in python. The objects point to a predecessor and eventually to their successors. I can not avoid having an 'ugly' if else clause in my `__init__` function.

```
class chain_link():
    def __init__(self, predecessor):
        self.predecessor = predecessor
        
        if predecessor == None:
            self.length = 1
            # attribtues specially calculated for the first object of the class

        else:
            self.length = self.predecessor.length + 1
            # attributes calculated based on the predecessor
```

Example usage:

```
chain = [chain_link(None)]
for i in range(100):
    chain.append(chain_link(chain[-1]))
```

Both initialisations (i.e. first and following) feature some specific code, that should be performed.
I am aware that I could define separate functions for the initialisation:

```
class chain_link():
    def __init__(self, predecessor):
        self.predecessor = predecessor
        
        if predecessor == None:
            self.init_first()
        else:
            self.init_normal()
            
    def init_first(self):
        self.length = 1

    def init_normal(self):    
        self.length = self.predecessor.length + 1
```

I have the (probably unhealthy) urge to try to avoid the conditional statement in the `__init__` function. Are there smarter ways? Are there more pythonic ways?

Comment: *"Both initialisations (i.e. first and following) feature some specific code"*: if you believe that should be possible without `if` statements, then it is essential you provide that specific code, so we can either propose a solution, or tell you why it cannot be done any better. I am reluctant to answer at this stage, as I can expect a comment like "OK, but this will not work for my case, because I need to execute this code: ....".

Comment: I agree with your statement. The questions is maybe a bit to general, but I do not expect a working solution for my case. I simply would like to know the different flavours of how you can handle such object initialisations.  I would appreciate your answer, even if it is not fully applicable to my problem.

Comment: What is the plan with the `chain` list? Does it support calling the `pop` method on any index? Does it need to support any deletion from it? What about slicing? I have some problems with that choice of data structure... which also holds me back from answering.

Comment: It does not need to support any deletion from it, neither do I worry about slicing etc. I am working on blockchain simulations hence the chained structure of the objects. I am merely using the chain list as a container to hold the chain links

Comment: Then what is the relevance of the `length` attribute in *each* object? Isn't the final length (i.e. `len(chain)`) enough?

Comment: I am not trying to optimise anything on the chain list, it is only an example of how the objects _could_ be working with each other. There can be multiple links of the same length in the list.

Comment: Confusing. I will leave this for someone else to look at.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, yes, in OOP it is a standard way of removing such ifs. It is called polymorphism.

Modifying your second example, you create a new chain_link_head that extends chain_link:

```
class chain_link():
....
    def init(self):    
        self.length = self.predecessor.length + 1
....


class chain_link_head(chain_link):
....
    def init(self):
        self.length = 1
....
```

Usage:

```
chain = [chain_link_head(None)]
for i in range(100):
    chain.append(chain_link(chain[-1]))
```

After initialization you can treat all the objects as chain_link, and disregard the fact that you have a chain_link_head. This shall be used only at object creation.

**However:**

- in many OOP languages, polymorphism does not work with constructors, so you will have to make a second init call, after the object is created. But with python this might work, you'll have to test it

**But more important!!:**

- For such simple examples I would not bother with all the overhead of creating a second class, and just go with the ifs. In case you will see that you have in many places such ifs with different behaviour, then I would consider using polymorphism.